# How can I get data I've saved into an Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a "Watch later" extension for Google Chrome. When I press the extension, it shows a pop-up. Here, there are 2 buttons and a p element.

The first button is for saving the actual url into the storage of Chrome.

The second button should put into the p element the url that I've saved when I pressed the first button.

Buuuuut this isn't working. :(

Here's my code:

```js
saveItem.onclick = function(element) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    var activeTabId = activeTab.id; // or do whatever you need

    chrome.storage.sync.set({ "activeTab": activeTabId }, function(){
      
  });

 });
};

checkWhatsSaved.onclick = function(element) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(["activeTab"], function(items){
    var item = String(items);
    alert(item);
    document.getElementById(urlDude).innerHTML = item;
    
});
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        button {
          height: 30px;
          width: 30px;
          outline: none;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="saveItem">save</button>
      <button id="checkWhatsSaved">load</button>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>

      <p id="urlDude">nothing to show. :(</p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `var item = items.activeTab`

Comment: @wOxxOm This is working... But now, I get a number, not the url. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You get what you save, which is activeTabId. You need to save `url` property of `activeTab` object. See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab).

Comment: Thanks! This is working. ^^ I have another question, the line of code `document.getElementById(urlDude).innerHTML = item;` is throwing and error because _Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null_. What it's wrong? Thanks again and apology this!

Comment: `urlDude` should be quoted e.g. `'urlDude'`